# Trying to Find Object Based on Coords in ArcGIS

Tags: php, arcgis

I'm sure this is fairly simple but I'm having a hard time finding documentation on how to find any objects that intersect a point in ArcGIS.  I have uploaded a map and I'd like to get the intersecting object and their properties.  I'd prefer if the solution was in PHP but if there is a solution in another language that is fine as well.

Comment: For clarification, I'd like to get any shapes that intersect the coordinate I'm looking up in the API.  The shapes have attributes that I need to have returned.  If I have to make two calls that is fine.

Answer (score 0):

If by "objects" and "point", you mean geometries shape, you could use an ArcGis GeometryService in Javascript, to perform an intersect 
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/geometryservice-amd.html between two geometries, a Point and a Polygon

We can even do this in Oracle db : http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/ST_Intersects/006z00000059000000/

If by "point"/"coord", you mean a click on a layer, that could help you https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/infotemplate-amd.html

Comment: Yes this is getting on the right track, the shapes have attributes that I'd like to get back, and I cannot find a way to get those attributes.

Comment: do you want the attributes of the shapes, by clicking on the shape ? maybe this answer will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42062363/display-attribute-value-from-arcgis-layer-to-html-textbox

Comment: I want to get the attributes programatically

Comment: here is some code to get attributes from an intersection between two geometries from two different layers :

Comment: `var query = new Query();
query.where = "OBJECTID > 0";
parcelsLayer.queryFeatures(query, polygonsFound);

function polygonsFound (polygons) {
  function showIntersection(intersection) {
    console.log(intersection.features);
  };

  function intersec(geo) {
    var query = new Query();
    query.geometry = geo;
    citiesLayer.queryFeatures(query, showIntersection);
  };

  var features = polygons.features;

  features.map(function (feature) {
    intersec(feature.geometry);
  });
}`